# « Encastrer » : nouveau terme ou usage abusif ?

Tags: sens, terminologie, néologismes

Le texte suivant est extrait d'un [article récent](https://www.msn.com/fr-fr/actualite/france/deux-jeunes-filles-de-16-ans-tu%C3%A9es-dans-un-accident-dans-le-lot-et-garonne/ar-AA1dATqG?ocid=msedgdhp&pc=U531&cvid=ca4e1a8c36c8450985c316e9c157d939&ei=46).

> Un terrible accident s’est produit vendredi soir vers 22 heures à Barbaste dans le Lot-et-Garonne, où deux jeunes filles âgées de 16 ans ont perdu la vie. Selon les premiers éléments, le conducteur, âgé de 18 ans et originaire d’Agen, habitant Condom, aurait perdu le contrôle de son véhicule pour une raison encore indéterminée. La voiture est allée s’encastrer dans un platane.

Les définitions du terme « encastrer » au [TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/encastrer) n"impliquent qu'une relation de pénétration, alors que la situation qui résulte lorsqu'un véhicule percute un arbre n'est jamais celle d'une pénétration de l'arbre par le véhicule ; c'est seulement l'inverse qui se produit et une partie du véhicule entoure alors l'arbre en partie, et  en plus ce n'est pas un cas courant parce que le véhicule est assez souvent simplement arrêté ou déporté sur un côté.

Le [Wiktionnaire](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/encastrer) ne laisse entrevoir aucune autre possibilité ; idem pour [l'internaute](https://www.linternaute.fr/dictionnaire/fr/definition/encastrer/), [Le Larousse](https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/encastrer/29112), et [Le Robert](https://dictionnaire.lerobert.com/definition/encastrer).

L'exemple de cet usage produit ci-dessus n'est pas le premier que je trouve ; le verbe « encastrer » est souvent utilisé dans ce contexte de véhicule qui percute soit un arbre soit autre chose.

S'agit-il d'un nouvel usage et doit-on l'accepter, ou bien est-ce clairement du non-sens qui se trouve colporté en raison de négligence répétée ?

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/147128/discussion-on-question-by-lph--encastrer--nouveau-terme-ou-usage-abusif); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 4):

Une voiture [encastrée dans un arbre](https://www.google.fr/search?q=%22voiture+encastr%C3%A9e+dans+un+platane%22&lr=&as_qdr=all&ei=pYipZMO1MImlkdUPw4mc2Aw&ved=0ahUKEwiDnM-Kvv__AhWJUqQEHcMEB8sQ4dUDCA4&oq=%22voiture+encastr%C3%A9e+dans+un+platane%22&gs_lcp=Cgxnd3Mtd2l6LXNlcnAQDEoECEEYAVChBljjEWD5GGgBcAB4AIABY4gB9gGSAQEzmAEAoAEBwAEB&sclient=gws-wiz-serp), [une balustrade](https://www.google.fr/search?q=%22voiture%20encastr%C3%A9e%20dans%20une%20balustrade%22&lr=&as_qdr=all&ei=6ompZLCKAZqikdUP06iIqAU&ved=0ahUKEwiwp5ylv___AhUaUaQEHVMUAlUQ4dUDCA4&oq=%22voiture%20encastr%C3%A9e%20dans%20une%20balustrade%22&gs_lcp=Cgxnd3Mtd2l6LXNlcnAQDEoECEEYAVDvBVjFXmCGbmgKcAB4AIABmAGIAYsSkgEEMzAuMZgBAKABAcABAQ&sclient=gws-wiz-serp), [un mur](https://www.google.fr/search?q=%22voiture%20encastr%C3%A9e%20dans%20un%20mur%22&lr=&as_qdr=all&ei=DoqpZLvALLCmkdUPvoWlyAE&ved=0ahUKEwi7_9y2v___AhUwU6QEHb5CCRkQ4dUDCA4&oq=%22voiture%20encastr%C3%A9e%20dans%20un%20mur%22&gs_lcp=Cgxnd3Mtd2l6LXNlcnAQDEoECEEYAVCWBljGKGCdOGgBcAB4AIABoQKIAfcEkgEFMC4zLjGYAQCgAQHAAQE&sclient=gws-wiz-serp), [une autre voiture](https://www.google.fr/search?q=%22voiture%20encastr%C3%A9e%20dans%20une%20autre%20voiture%22&lr=&as_qdr=all&ei=NoqpZPa7GJOmkdUP6Ni08A8&ved=0ahUKEwj2rtLJv___AhUTU6QEHWgsDf4Q4dUDCA4&oq=%22voiture%20encastr%C3%A9e%20dans%20une%20autre%20voiture%22&gs_lcp=Cgxnd3Mtd2l6LXNlcnAQDEoECEEYAVD-mQFY280BYPDUAWgCcAB4AIABcogB_g2SAQQ4LjExmAEAoAEBwAEB&sclient=gws-wiz-serp), est quelque chose de très habituel (malheureusement) et que j'ai toujours entendu et il ne s'agit pas d'un nouvel emploi.

Cet emploi  correspond à la définition du [TLF](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/encastrer)

> − P. anal.
> A. Embourber, coincer. »
> Dans le cas d'une voiture je retiendrai « coincer ».

Le *Dictionnaire culturel en langue française* ne passe même pas par ce détour de « coincer » :

> entre de vieux murs sans fenêtres, faits de débris de toutes les époques de l’histoire et où, çà et là, s’encastrent une pierre hébraïque, un marbre romain. (P. Loti) Par anal. La voiture s'est encastrée dans le mur.

Dans tous les cas il s'agit d'[une analogie](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/analogie).

From [a comment by @jlliagre](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/53326/encastrer-nouveau-terme-ou-usage-abusif/53328?noredirect=1#comment112751_53328) :

> On emploie encastré uniquement dans le cas où le contact est maintenu, a entraîné une grosse déformation qui empêche tout ou partie des mouvements naturels du véhicule.

---

---

Cette expression se trouve essentiellement dans les rubriques faits divers de la presse locale, écrite et parlée, et c'est pour cela qu'il est relativement difficile de trouver des usages anciens. Une recherche dans [books.google](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22s%27encastrer%20dans%20un%20arbre%22&tbm=bks&ei=2DKsZOy6KoOmkdUP1vSnmAI&ved=0ahUKEwjshuzWyISAAxUDU6QEHVb6CSMQ4dUDCAg&oq=%22s%27encastrer%20dans%20un%20arbre%22&gs_lcp=Cg1nd3Mtd2l6LWJvb2tzEAxQwyxYmkRgmltoAXAAeACAATyIAdQFkgECMTWYAQCgAQHAAQE&sclient=gws-wiz-books) de "s'encastrer dans un arbre", fait quand même ressortir de nombreux exemples, et, parmi ceux du siècle dernier celui-ci trouvé dans un roman de 1991 :

> La 309 avait butté par l'avant et le pavillon était venu s'encastrer dans un arbre. Elle était restée le coffre en l'air, les phares plantés dans le sol. (*L'Outrage en plus*, Serge Livrozet · 1991)

Un autre exemple a attiré mon attention puisqu'on trouve l'expression dans un ouvrage de 2013 consacré aux assurances ([L'assurance « Collective Accidents de Droit Commun »](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Assurance_Collective_Accidents_de_Droit/nniGBwAAQBAJ?hl=fr&gbpv=1)) et qui rapporte des paroles juridiques :

> « La victime circulait de A. vers C., elle perdit pour une raison indéterminée le contrôle de son véhicule, qui alla s'encastrer dans un arbre et, selon le témoin, qui a vu le choc... »

---

Comment: Non, ça ne correspond pas à « embourber » ni « coincer ». « encastrer dans un mur » : oui.

Comment: @LPH Pourquoi laisses-tu entendre que None a dit que ça correspondrait à *embourber* alors qu'au contraire, elle ne retient pas ce premier sens ? Pourquoi refuses-tu le sens de coincer ? Une voiture qui s'est encastrée dans un arbre n'est plus libre de ses mouvement, elle est... **coincée**. TLFi: *Coincé: Qui est immobilisé sous l'action d'agents extérieurs.*

Comment: @jlliagre N'est pas coincé qui peut reculer ou passer sur un côté ; l'analogie telle que comprise dans le TLFi, se voit dans les exemples du TLFi : la boue entoure les roues, la personne est cernée de tous côtés par le foule, on a bien une analogie ; on n'a pas cette analogie dans le cas de l'arbre, et le coincement, s'il y en a un, résulte de la situation inverse, c'est le véhicule qui se repli sur l'arbre, l'arbre qui est encastré dans le véhicule, et ça c'est extrêmement rare ; de toute façon c'est l'inverse.

Comment: @LPH Mais une voiture _qui vient de s'écraser dans un platane_ ne peut ni reculer, ni passer sur le côté, donc elle est bien _coincée_. Mais entre experts des accidents voiture sur platane, nous sommes d'accord j'espère que tout cela dépend du type de la boîte de vitesse, ainsi que de l'âge dudit platane, ainsi que de la saison, puisque si les roues sont recouvertes de boue, il s'agirait plutôt d'un _embourbement-écrasage_ du troisième type, n'est-ce pas? Sauf si le véhicule (de moins de 2 tonnes) se _replit_ sur une branche maîtresse, auquel cas il s'agirait d'un _encastrement inverse_.

Comment: Mais de toute façon, dans tous ces cas de figure, le terme _encastrement_ sans précision est clairement _faux_, c'est du _non sens colporté_, probablement par des _moutons_, et les journalistes du Parisien qui ont écrit cet article et osé utiliser ce mot doivent être sévèrement réprimandés, voire licenciés, ou peut-être forcés à copier le dictionnaire mot à mot, et contraints à déclarer solennellement qu'ils n'utiliseront les mots que conformément à leur définition exacte dans le TLFi.

Comment: @Frank Vous dites donc d'une voiture en panne, parce qu'elle ne peut ni reculer ni avancer, qu'elle est coincée ? Quels enfantillages ! Cette remarque sur votre première élucubration étant faite, je vais m'abstenir de m'avancer plus loin dans votre salmigondis, vous radotez.

Comment: @LPH _Salmigondis_ et _radotage_ sont _archi-faux_. Veuillez consulter la définition des mots _ironie_ et _sarcasme_ dans le TLFi.

Comment: @LPH Non, *encastrer* est bien le terme qui convient. Une voiture entrée en collision avec un arbre mais qui a "rebondi" dessus n'est pas encastrée dans ledit arbre. On emploie *encastré* uniquement dans le cas où le contact est maintenu, a entraîné une grosse déformation qui empêche tout ou partie des mouvements naturels du véhicule.

Comment: @jlliagre Personnellement, je déconseillerai cet usage ; je le considère comme une perversion de l'idée fondamentale, qui a été jusqu'à nos jours assez bien préservée. L'idée essentielle est celle de collision, de percuter ; c'est trop arbitraire.

Comment: @LPH L'idée que les mots véhiculent une idée fondamentale et qu'ils devraient s'y tenir à la lettre au fil des siècles est tout simplement absurde, contraire à toute approche scientifique de l'étude des langues.

Comment: @jlliagre L'idée que cela aurait été le cas au cours des siècles est plutôt absurde, mais l'idée que les utilisateurs d'une langue peuvent et doivent aller contre ce grain plus ou moins naturel, ne l'est pas. D'ailleurs on peut lire de nombreuses source dans lesquelles est expliqué pourquoi ne pas suivre tel ou tel usage, les raisons visant souvent à éliminer l'incohérent, l'illogique en général.

Comment: L'usage prévaut sur toute autre considération, L'usage se contrefout des ouvrages prescriptivistes, il a le temps avec lui.

Comment: @jlliagre Oui! LBU le reconnaît explicitement dès son introduction, et se garde bien de vouloir être trop prescriptif, ils ne savent que trop bien que les langues évoluent perpétuellement et qu'on ne peut pas les figer dans un carcan de règles. L'usage évolue. On est familier avec l'usage du moment, dans sa région et ses circonstances. Ceci dit, libre à LPH de ne jamais utiliser le mot _encastrer_, mais il ne faut pas venir nous dire qu'on a _tout faux_ et qu'on fait une _erreur_ si on l'utilise.

Comment: @Frank La GGF, extrait de l'intro « Elle vise à dire comment on écrit et on parle, et non comment il faut écrire ou parler.  [...] Notre objectif  est de proposer un système cohérent permettant de décrire la diversité des usages actuels. [Cet ouvrage]  inclut des usages condamnés par la norme, à partir du moment où ils sont fréquents et appropriés à certaines situations ».

Comment: @None Tout cela converge effectivement.